# Solidjs router does not render

Tags: javascript, routes, solid-js

I already searched a lot and could not find an answer. In my SolidJs app, the second route is not redered in root element:

```
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from "solid-app-router"
import { useNavigate } from 'solid-app-router';

const Login = lazy(() => import("./pages/login"));
const Operation = lazy(() => import("./pages/operation"));

export default function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const location = useLocation();
  onMount(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (!token && location.pathname !== '/') {
      navigate("/", { replace: true });
    }
    if (token && location.pathname === '/') {
      navigate("/operations", { replace: true });
    }
  });
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' component={Login} />
      <Route path='/operations' component={Operation} />
    </Routes>
  )
}
```

Everything looks OK at component Operation and if I call this component in first route like bellow it work:

```
<Route path='/' component={Operation} />
```

Comment: Just checking you've got <Router> wrapping App?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this for a while and realised that the application needs to make reference to the `Routes` by means of an `<A>` tag.

If you look at this [part of the docs](https://github.com/solidjs/solid-router#create-links-to-your-routes), it mentions that these tags include an `active` class which seems to be used to tell the application to actually bundle this component on build time otherwise by default it is not included.

So if you put `<A href="/operations">Operations</A>` somewhere in your homepage like a Navbar, that page/component should bundle in on deployment.

By default though all routes in `Routes` in `dev` environment should work so if it is not working in `dev` environment I would just check that the module is being resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The root component should be wrapped in `Router` component.